# Sending a Json from a POJO to server tomcat

Tags: java, json, servlets, pojo

so i ve been searching my question throw out internet and didnt excatly satisfied with answered ! what i m looking for is some features of jackson or streamoutputwriter to do send a Json to my server ! i ve found a way to get a json from my server

```
public GetJsonfromServer() {

    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        URL restServiceURL = new URL(targetURL);

        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) restServiceURL.openConnection();
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "HTTP GET Request Failed with Error code : " + httpConnection.getResponseCode());
        }
        BufferedReader responseBuffer = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader((httpConnection.getInputStream())));
        String output = "";

        System.out.println("Output from Server:  \n");
        while ((output = responseBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
            Object s = mapper.readValue(output, Object.class);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        BufferedWriter requestBuffer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(httpConnection.getOutputStream()));
        requestBuffer.write("hello from client");
        requestBuffer.flush();

        httpConnection.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this works fine for me i can convert the json that i get from server to object ! i would be glad if you help me to find a way to send a json to server with desired method (GET,POST , ..) !( i m using java on eclipse )

Comment: So, what's your client? A java application? a web page? there IS corresponding client object for you to send http request to server. And sending request with json is normal task for these clients.

Comment: Such as HTTPClient in java, Ajax call in web page.

Comment: @VincentZhang i m using java application !

Comment: Then there are many libraries providing HttpClient, with which you can do http get, post, with json to your server.  Such as org.apache.httpcomponents. httpclient

Comment: @VincentZhang thank you